# Like button appear when hovering over image

Tags: html, image, avatar

Would anybody be able to point in the direction of adding a like system when hovering over a image?

I've tried searching on google for an answer but I can only seem to come across hit counters, which I'm not looking for.

```
<div id="nextpage">
    <a href="pages/2.php">Next</a>
</div>

<div id="header">
    <div class="headerleft">AceyAvatars - Created by     <ahref="http://steamcommunity.com/id/aceywolf3" target="_blank">AceyWolf</a> |    THE PLACE FOR A FRESH AVATAR!
</div>

<div class="headerright">
    <script language="javascript" src="js/liveclock.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="imagecontent">
    <div id="howto">
        <div class="rightclick"><font color="yellow">TO USE AN IMAGE:</font> RIGHT CLICK -> SAVE IMAGES AS <font color="#fff">|</font> STEAM: <font color="yellow"> EDIT PROFILE -> SELECT IMAGE -> UPLOAD</font></div>
    <div class="leftclick">IMAGES UPLOADED: 250</div>
</div>

<div class="images">
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/1.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/2.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/3.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/4.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/5.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/6.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="images2">
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/7.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/8.png" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/9.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/10.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/11.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/12.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="images">
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/13.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/14.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image"/></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/15.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/16.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/17.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
<div class="actualimage"><img src="css/images/avatars/18.jpg" width="184" height="184" title="Right Click -> Save Image" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

--

```
div#header {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #2980b9;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.headerleft {
float: left;
font-size: 1.3em;
padding: 12px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.headercenter {
float: left;
margin-left: 70px;
}
.headerright {
float: right;
padding: 12px;
font-size: 1.3em;
color: #000;
}
/*////////////////////////////////*/
div#imagecontent {
text-align: center;
width: 1300px;
height: 800px;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.images {
padding: 20px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
margin-top: 13px;
border: 3px solid #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.images2 {
padding: 20px;
width: 1230px;
background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0);
margin-top: -18px;
margin-bottom: -32px;
margin-left: 10px;
border-left: 3px solid #000;
border-right: 3px solid #000;
font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.actualimage {
line-height: 0;
border: 3px solid #000;
width: 184px;
height: 184px;
display: inline-block;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
/*//////////////////////////////////////////*/
div#nextpage {
transition: 0.3s;
position: fixed;
width: 110px;
padding: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-left: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 94%;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #2980b9;
}
div#nextpage:hover {
transition: 0.3s;
margin-left: 92%;
width: 140px;
}
div#nextpage a {
color: #2980b9;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.3em;
transition: 0.3s;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
}
div#nextpage a:hover {
font-size: 1.4em;
transition: 0.3s;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
}
div#previouspage {
transition: 0.3s;
position: fixed;
width: 130px;
padding: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
float: left;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #2980b9;
text-align: right;
}
div#previouspage:hover {
transition: 0.5s;
width: 150px;
}
div#previouspage a {
color: #2980b9;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.3em;
transition: 0.3s;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
text-align: right;
}
div#previouspage a:hover {
font-size: 1.4em;
transition: 0.3s;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
}
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////*/
div#howto {
background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0);
width: 1230px;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-bottom: -13px;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-left: 2px solid #000;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
padding: 20px;
}
.rightclick {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-top: -8px;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
}
.leftclick {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-top: -8px;
font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
}
/*///////////////////////////*/
div#menubar {
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,0.6);
position: fixed;
text-align: right;
margin-top: 70px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.menulinks {
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like [this in content link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/pure-css-image-hover/)

Comment: Thank you! I just need to find a "like" system now.

Comment: you can change the second image to like image